# Erro 404 no projeto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, htaccess, xampp

Tenho algumas configurações no arquivo `config/app.php` do meu projeto, como:

```
'base_domain' => 'aplicacao.com.br'
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://cliente.aplicacao.com.br')
```

No meu arquivos de rotas, tenho:

```
Route::domain('cliente.' . config('app.base_domain'))->group(function () {...
```

Configurei um virtual host (com o xampp), que possui a seguinte configuração:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.aplicacao.com.br
    ServerAlias aplicacao.com.br
    DocumentRoot "meu diretório"
    <Directory "meu diretório">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Quando acesso a aplicação pelo navegador, ele nunca encontra as views, sempre dá o erro 404 (como se não estivesse encontrando o domínio). Minha configuração está errada? Teria que configurar mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode se apropriar de um domínio **.com.br** e simplesmente configurar ele no seu servidor apache como um virtual host, isso não funciona.

Para essa finalidade que você deseja existem os domínios **.test**. Para configurar esse domínio no Windows faça o seguinte:

1. Acesse `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.
2. Edite o arquivo `hosts` com o editor de texto que preferir, pode ser o bloco de notas.
3. Supondo que você deseje criar o domínio **aplicacao.test**, vai deixar o arquivo com o seguinte conteudo:

   ```
   #
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   ::1 localhost
   127.0.0.1 aplicacao.test
   ::1 aplicacao.test
   ```
4. Com isso você terá registrado esse domínio local no seu sistema operacional.

Agora modifique também seu virtual server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aplicacao.test
    ServerAlias www.aplicacao.test
    DocumentRoot "meu diretório"
    <Directory "meu diretório">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nesse arquivo vale fazer algumas ressalvas. A primeira é o `ServerAlias` é que tem o **www** do domíno, o `ServerName` é o domínio puro. A segunda é, quando for escrever o "meu diretório" descrito ali, observe que no `DocumentRoot` o diretório não tem o carácter `/`(barra) no final e na tag `Directory` sim deve ter o carácter `/`(barra) ao final do caminho.

Feito isso reinicie seu apache (no seu caso o xampp). Ajuste os arquivos no Laravel para esse novo domínio e deve funcionar corretamente.